# PyMongo authentication failing

Tags: python, mongodb, authentication, pymongo, nosql

I set up a database with mongolab where the db had the same name as the collection. I decided I didnt like this deleted it and made a better naming scheme. I added a new user/password to for the new db and tried to authenticated. It keeps failing. Not sure why. I have double check my credentials and they are correct. I have checked the URI that mongolab provides and that is correct also. This code worked well for the first db.

this is my login code

```
def __init__(self, user_id, password, database, collection):
        # mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds017205.mlab.com:17205/words
        mongodb_uri = "mongodb://" + user_id + ":" + password + "@ds017205.mlab.com:17205/" + database
        client = pymongo.MongoClient(mongodb_uri)
        db = client[database]
        self.collection = db[collection] # is declared in class
```

this generates the following errors

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Austin\PycharmProjects\Words\test_mongodb.py", line 15, in testUpdate
    results = self.mongodb_obj.update(test)
  File "C:\Users\Austin\PycharmProjects\Words\mongodb.py", line 38, in update
    upsert=True
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 2235, in update
    with self._socket_for_writes() as sock_info:
  File "C:\Python33\lib\contextlib.py", line 48, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 718, in _get_socket
    with server.get_socket(self.__all_credentials) as sock_info:
  File "C:\Python33\lib\contextlib.py", line 48, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymongo\server.py", line 152, in get_socket
    with self.pool.get_socket(all_credentials, checkout) as sock_info:
  File "C:\Python33\lib\contextlib.py", line 48, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 541, in get_socket
    sock_info.check_auth(all_credentials)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 306, in check_auth
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 436, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 416, in _authenticate_default
    return _authenticate_scram_sha1(credentials, sock_info)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 216, in _authenticate_scram_sha1
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 213, in command
    read_concern)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 99, in command
    helpers._check_command_response(response_doc, None, allowable_errors)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 196, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.
```

Help with this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What version of pymongo and MongoDB are you using? As per the [authentication examples doc page](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/authentication.html), do you need to escape any characters in the password?

Comment: I'm using the most recent version of mongodb and pymongo.  downloaded the most recent a three or four days go.  did a pip install for pymongo

Comment: just tried to escape specials in password and got the same result. also it worked before without escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the code... the db user set up entered the incorrect password the same twice in the setup box so it was accepted then when the code was trying to use the actual correct answer it wouldn't work for obvious reasons. thanks all for looking